# Ubuntu 18.04 netplan.io how to prevent the creation of 2 default gateways

Tags: networking, server, dhcp, netplan, systemd-networkd

When I add 2 interfaces (**eth0** LAN, **eth1** WAN) with static IPs (or maybe also with DHCP), Ubuntu 18.04 Server is adding 2 default gateways. Thats not the goal.

How can I define only 1 default gateway?

File: `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml`

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      addresses:
        - 172.16.1.22/16
      gateway4: 172.16.0.1
      nameservers:
        search: [mydomain.internal]
        addresses: [172.16.1.2, 172.16.1.1]
    eth1:
      addresses:
      - 172.19.3.235/24
      gateway4: 172.19.3.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [195.50.xxx.xxx,195.50.xxx.xxx]
```

`ip route` shows:

```
user@server:~$ ip route
default via 172.19.3.1 dev eth1 proto static
default via 172.16.0.1 dev eth0 proto static
172.16.0.0/16 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 172.16.1.22
172.19.3.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 172.19.3.134
```

2 default GWs......

In my case, the default GW from **eth1** is the one and only I need.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the gateway configuration from the `eth0` interface.

Omit the line which says `gateway4: 172.16.0.1`.

You will still be able to reach hosts in the `172.16.x.y` subnet through `eth0`, since it's directly connected there.

If you need to access other hosts in that network (for example, an intranet with private addresses in the [RFC1918 ranges](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918)), then just add static routes to access those networks using the 172.16.0.1 gateway. See [this reference](https://netplan.io/reference#routing) for routing in Netplan, which should help you add static routes.

If you get your IPs through DHCP, it should be mostly the same... But then you need the DHCP server that hands you an IP on `eth0` **not** to set any gateways... There doesn't seem to be a good way in Netplan to disable a gateway you receive from DHCP. (Though networkd can do that, see [this comment on another answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062902/ubuntu-18-04-netplan-static-routes/1062931#comment1740347_1062931) for an attempt to address that.)